# Service discovery ecs aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, devops, amazon-ecs

I am trying to connect from one container to another container by using service discovery for private network in ecs where I have used dynamic port mapping. I looked for this solution everywhere but I am not able to fine the solution. Help needed

Answer (score 3):

ECS with EC2 launch type and **Dynamic Port Mapping** would mean SRV records for DNS resolution.

[Service Discovery Considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html#service-discovery-considerations)

> If the task definition that your service task specifies uses the bridge or host network mode, an SRV record is the only supported DNS record type.

So DNS records for a service discovery service can be queried within your VPC. They use the following format

> **service_discovery_service name.service_discovery_namespace.**

Querying the SRV record will return a set of IP addresses and ports per task. Once you have IP:Port, you can hit running application.

You can check out the sample application [here](https://github.com/prshntattri1/ECS) which does the DNS resolution. Feel free to let me know if you have any specific issues/questions.